# Is it possible to not show android notifications from some apps in custom launcher?

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement to hide notification from some apps that are not showing in my custom launcher and I want to fulfil this with 1. Disable the app that is hidden in launcher or 2. Disable only notification of the app.

For 1. I think the root is required. Please let me know if I am wrong.

For 2. I don't have a particular solution.

Please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We would like to see your attempt.

Comment: I am looking for the feasibility of the solution for a problem to show only specific apps in android and I found that we can build custom launcher to display only those specific apps. I have seen the tutorials and it seems feasible but then I have another problem to stop another app's notification as they can be open by a user via notification. I am sorry, I don't have my own code yet.